# Functions on two arrays

Tags: javascript

I have the following code written already. The idea is to iterate through two arrays so that at every index the contents are multiplied together which is then remembered and added to the product of the next indices ect. I can't figure out what is wrong with the code I wrote. Can anyone tell me what is wrong with it? Thank you!

```
function main() { 
    var first = [1,2,3,4]; 
    var second = [5,6,7,8]; 
    var sum = 0;

    function iterate(a, fun) { 
        var n; n = a.length; 
        var i; 

        for (i=0; i<n; i++) { 
            fun(a[i]);
         } 
    }

    multiply(); 

    function multiply(x,y) { 
        iterate(first, out());

         function out(total1) { 
            x = total1;

             iterate(second, inn());

             function inn(total2){

                 y = total2;

                 sum += x*y;

             } 
        }
     }

    document.write(sum);
}

main();
```

Comment: The formatting is horrible, for one :)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
iterate(first,out());
```

you need

```
iterate(first,out);
```

You want to pass the function `out` to `iterate`, not the result of calling `out` with no arguments which is what you are doing now.

And similarly

```
iterate(second, inn());
```

should be

```
iterate(second, inn);
```

Comment: woh! I got an answer! It's not the right one but it is printing out something now! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I know you asked for a fix for your existing code, but here's an alternative:

```
var first = [1, 2, 3, 4], second = [5, 6, 7, 8];

first.reduce(function (x, y, i) { 
   return x + y * second[i];
}, 0); // => 70
```